# How to reference submodule non-java resources (templates, js, css, etc)

Tags: java, playframework

I have playframework application that uses my playframework module.
There are some static content and views/tags in the module.
My app works fine when I run it in dev mode.
But when deployed to tomcat6, it results in

```
TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : tags/templateFromModule.html
or tags/templateFromModule.tag
```

I can find such template in deployed application in:
WEB-INF\application\precompiled\templates\from_module_myModuleName\app\views\tags\

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In your module define your static resources on `/public/MODULENAME/javascripts/foobar.js`, then from your application you can do `@{'/public/MODULENAME/javascripts/foobar.js'}`. Don't forget to turn off the `/public` route from your module when importing into the application.

Comment: Thanks, What about tag? Is it possible to use #{myModuleTag} on my app pages?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I put some static content (js) into mymodule/public, and deploy myapp using command 'play war -o dest_path/myapp.war' then public content from my module is not included into deployment directory.

Comment: I believe it includes it from /public/MODULENAME/, not /public.